# How to obtain the IP of a network printer from a list of printers through Java

Tags: java, networking, printing, ip, port

I have a database that contains a list of IP addresses for various printers. The users will choose a printer to print on, and the way I see this workng out is that the java application will iterate through the list of printers until it finds the one with the matching IP address. Using the PrintService class, I've been able to successfully generate a list of PrintServices with the following code:

```
DocFlavor flavor = new DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM("application/octet-stream");
PrintService pServices[] = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(flavor, null);
```

When I debug and step through the code, I am able to locate the printer. I can identify it based on the name I gave it when I installed the drivers to my local PC. However, as stated above, I need to find it based on IP address. When I put the current value of pServices on watch, I am able to see the value of the IP address in the "port" variable. Through some quick searching, I found that there is no public "getter" method for the "port" variable. Is there an easier way of doing this, or is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Do you _have to_ do it by IP or is this just an approach you came up with?

Comment: This was the approach that was deemed the safest.

Comment: Well, personally, I'd go for the PrintService's name. Assuming that this will be used in a corporate environment, Printers should be installed with a unique name. I do not see an easy way to make that mapping. But I am not experienced with printing ...